# Java Mail - how to create a link for a shared folder on linux and access the same in Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, jakarta-mail, shared-directory

I would like to send out an email using JavaMail API that contains a shared folder link on Linux.

What would be the format to create this link.

And, when the same e-mail is opened on Windows and the shared folder is accessed, how will the folder download (inter-OS communication)?

Answer (score 1):

There are no shared folder links that work across arbitrary email senders and receivers.

The simple answer is, put the data on a web server and send an http URL.